# What happens when .sum and .to_a.sum give diferente results in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have partly solved an issue but am trying to understand what's happening.

I get data from my database:

```
rides = Ride.all

rides.sum(:value) returns 224.62 

rides.to_a.sum(&:value) returns 213.93
```

213.93 is the correct result.

I read in other questions that this is an issue for quite a few people but didn't find the solution yet. What might be the reasons for that, where can I start to investigate?

One thought was that I use soft delete and the first query might ignore deleted row, but in this case there are no deleted row so this is not the reason.

Comment: Can you post db schema for `Ride` model?

Comment: When you met some kind of magic, you have to start Rails console in `development` (`pry` is highly recommended). Start to dig from watch SQL for `Ride.all.sum(:value)` and `Ride.all.to_a`.